# Scanning software not recognizing my Epson xp201 all in one

Tags: linux, linux-mint

there, Started using Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon Rebecca. Pretty stable and nice functioning. Installed the driver of my All in One Epson xp 201; it prints, but the scanning software (Simple Scan) not reconize it. What can I do to get it scan? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Going to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule and doing a search for `XP-201` gives some hits.

Following them eventually leads you to
http://support.epson.net/linux/src/scanner/iscan/ and 
http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html

See also http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html

No idea whether these work, because I don't own an Epson scanner.

Comment: Thanks, Faheem. I'll check on those sites. The Rebecca Mint is working wonderfully, except for the scanning issue with my All in One Epson...

Comment: Hi, Faheem, Facing another issue: Bought a new Lenovo ideapad 100 14iby. Came with W 8.1. Installed Mint 17.3 but there's no way the distro starts. Changed Bios to Legacy, etc... The machine will always boot to W 8.1. If you or any other Linux friend has a suggestion, I'll appreciate it... Thanks..

Comment: @Martin Ask a question about it on the site. What happened with the scanner?